# CMS Made Simple - Installer 500 Error

Tags: php, cmsmadesimple

I am seeing a 500 error when running cmsms-2.1.6-install.php

What I have tried so far:

- Checked error logs. They show the 500 error on the hit. The description is simlply "-"
- Verified PHP at required version (5.6)
- Tried previous version of CMSMS (2.1.5)
- CHMOD installers - 777
- Uploaded a PHPINFO and ran it - Returned as expected. Used this to verify PHAR enabled
- Hosting is running PHP on Linux.
- Verified its not the .htaccess file by deleting it - Still throws 500 Server Error

Any ideas/suggestions appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked at the server's error logs?

Comment: Yes forgot to mention this. Post edited. Thanks.

Comment: I think a htaccess file is generating the 500 error.. most likly the htaccess file is using a uninstalled Apache module

Comment: I had a very simple .htaccess file which for surity I've since deleted -  I still get the 500 Error. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now solved this. The CMS Made Simple installation PHP file needs to be uploaded in FTP Binary mode as it contains compressed sections.